# Función Include no interpreta el código HTML

Tags: php, html, css, outlook

Estoy creando una intranet para mi departamento, la cual quiero que sirva de repositorio para diferentes comunicados que he enviando por correo electrónico.

Para intentar agilizar el proceso y tener todo el histórico, he guardado esos comunicados desde outlook exportándolos como html. Si abrimos ese comunicado desde local en el navegador se muestra correctamente.

El resultado de dicha exportación sería este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La intranet sigue el MVC, por lo que paso al controlador un código interno que tienen todos los comunicados, y este se encarga de buscarlo en la bbdd, y renderizar la página oportuna.

Código del Controller:

```
public static function read__Comunicado(Router $router){

            //Obtenemos el id que hemos pasado por el método get en la url
                $codigo_interno = $_GET['codigo_interno'];
                
            //buscamos los metadatos del comunicado
                $comunicado = Comunicado::findByCodigo($codigo_interno);

            //Cargamos la dirección donde se encuentra el comunicado que queremos mostrar
                $articulo = "../com" . "/{$comunicado->codigo_interno}.html";

            //Invovamos el método router
                $router->render('/intranet/comunicado' , [

                    //Ahora le pasamos los datos
                        'comunicado' => $comunicado,
                        'articulo' => $articulo,        
            
                ]);
        }
```

La página que carga el render es la siguiente:

```
<head>

       <title> <? echo $comunicado->titulo; ?> </title>
    
</head>

<main class="main">

      <!-- Comunicado -->
        <div class='comunicado'>

            <?php 

                if(file_exists($articulo)){

                    include($articulo);

                }
                else{

                    echo 'No se ha encontrado ningún artículo con ese código. Disculpe las molestias.';

                }
            
            ?>

        </div>

</main>

</html>
```

El problema es que, al renderizar la página, carga una especie de código corrompido, como si no fuera capaz de interpretarlo, tal y como muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si el problema es del archivo exportado o si la función "include" no es la correcta para este caso, ¿Alguien  sabe que puede estar pasando y como se puede solucioar?

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cuando tienes codigo html dentro de una base de datos y lo intentas imprimir, el sistema te imprimira explicitamente el contenido de la bd, puedes probar con imprimir los datos con esta funcion ```html_entity_decode($datos_de_la_bd)```

Comment: ¡Hola Ernesto! Gracias por tu respuesta. El código html está fuera de la base de datos, en un archivo .html. En la bbdd solo se buscan los metadatos de la comunicación que quiero mostrar. He probado a usar la función html_entity_decode pero tampoco da resultado.